# Firebase anonymous rest auth

Tags: c++, rest, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use the Firebase Realtime Database (not Cloud Firestore) in a desktop application via the REST api. The application is written in C++ and I don't need any user authentication (like Google or Facebook login), but I want to secure my database, so I need anonymous authentication.

What will be the best practice for that? I can't find any information regarding this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use Firebase but don't want to use the database or the authentication?

Comment: I primarily want to use the Firebase Database (with anonymous auth), but I don't want to use it on mobile, so I can't use the SDKs for that. Is Unity able to use the Firebase environment on desktop or only mobile?

Comment: This is going to be tough to answer because your question and comments don't agree. The question states *but I don't need the realtime database feature* and your comment states *I primarily want to use the Firebase Database*. The realtime database and Firebase Database are the same thing. Maybe you are referring to Firebase Storage? This question is related to platform capabilities and not directly related to a specific programming issue. I would head over the the [Firebase Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-gb#!forum/firebase-talk). I believe the answer is no for desktop.

Comment: I edit my question. I don't need the "realtime" feature (this is only possible on mobile) and I can use Firebase with REST (tested it with curl), but I can't find how to auth via REST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use the REST API to sign in an anonymous user and get a Firebase ID token to use with database.
To sign in anonymously:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-anonymously

To send authenticated requests to the db:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token

Comment: Yeah, this was my missing link. I always read https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth and this only told half of the story. Thanks.

Comment: So does that mean that provided anonymous auth is enabled, anyone can sign in anonymously if they have the API key?

Comment: Yeah but each time a new anonymous user ID is allocated.

Comment: I tried that, but now I have Unauthorized request, despite I added the generated id_token to the request !